# Loading changes for Component failed

Tags: sapui5

When I start the app, I've got the following error message:

> Loading changes for ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.Component failed!
>   Error code: 404

It happens because of the smartFilterBar:

```
<smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="SelectionFilterBar" entitySet="ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION" search="onSearchClass">
    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
    </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
</smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
```

The network traffic shows:

[image]

It seems, that an interface could not be reached.

What am I doing wrong?
Hint: Starting the app at the first time, everything works as expected. After refreshing the app, I received the error.

The content of the component file:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "ch/mindustrie/ZMM_CLASSIFICATION/model/models"
], function (UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("ch.mindustrie.ZMM_CLASSIFICATION.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        /**
         * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
         * @public
         * @override
         */
        init: function () {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // enable routing
            this.getRouter().initialize();

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        }
    });
});
```

**Update**

I debugged the app and saw:

[image]

UI5 try to download appversion and it failed.

Comment: Could you find any solution for this? It seems when we use any smart items and want to move to object view it tries to load the old version of Component!!!

Comment: I found the solutions finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you received the following 2 errors in your `SAPUI5` application in the `WEBIDE` environment regarding missing of `/appconfig/fioriSandboxConfig.json` and `Loading changes for ...Component failed` as shown in the following picture:

[image: Error messages in console output]

Then simply add the following `.json` files with empty body `- only put {} as the content in the *.json files-` and then you will not see the errors anymore.

1. Beside of the `webapp` folder create a new folder and name it `appconfig`, then inside of this new folder create a new file and name it `fioriSandboxConfig.json`, and finally add `{}` as the content of the `json` file.
2. Beside of the `Component.js` file create a new file and name it `Component-changes.json` and fill it with `{}` again.

Refresh your app to check the errors gone from console hopefully!

[image: Created files in WEBIDE]

For some reasons we don't see these error messages in `Fiori Launchpad`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forgotten following in your controller:
[image]